# Unity RPC Null reference exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, rpc

I'm trying to make my first server/client game on unity, and get stuck with RPC. I'm getting a very strange Null reference exception here:

```
for (int b = 1; b <= Network.connections.Length; b++)
{   
    playerList[b] = genPlayer(Network.connections[b-1]);
    Debug.Log(
        "player " + b + 
        " has ip " + Network.connections[b - 1].ipAddress + 
        " port " + Network.connections[b - 1].port + 
        " with ID " + playerList[b].ID + 
        " and info: " + playerList[b].info.guid);
    networkView.RPC("GetID", playerList[b].info, playerList[b].ID, b);
    ResendHand(playerList[b]);
}
```

while the genPlayer:

```
public player genPlayer(NetworkPlayer plr)
{
    Debug.Log("the new player added from: " + plr.ipAddress);                   
    player pl = new player();
    pl.ID = getID();//just a random int
    pl.card1 = getCard(pl.ID); //random card
    pl.card2 = getCard(pl.ID);
    pl.card3 = getCard(pl.ID);
    pl.card4 = getCard(pl.ID);
    pl.card5 = getCard(pl.ID);
    pl.score = 0;
    pl.vote = 0;
    pl.info = plr;            
    Debug.Log("the player was generated successfully with  " +  "ID " + pl.ID);
    return pl;
}
```

And here are messages:

> the new player added from: 169.254.80.80
>
> the player was generated successfully with  ID 664652695
>
> player 1 has ip 169.254.80.80 port 50571 with ID 664652695 and info: 1
>
> NullReferenceException ServerOperations.StartTheGame () (at
>   Assets/ServerOperations.cs:66)

Comment: Do not use [tag:Unity] for questions about the Unity Game engine, the tag Unity is for the [Unity Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) by Microsoft.

Comment: Which line is line 66?

Comment: Check if your `networkView` object is null.

Comment: line 66: networkView.RPC("GetID", playerList[b].info, playerList[b].ID, b);

Comment: networkPlayer object is not null, and other RPC functions, that use RPC.Server or RPC.Others are working

Comment: There's nothing strange about this at all. You clearly did not use a debugger on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Going over the Unity3D docs for making an RPC call.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkView.RPC.html

I see this format for making an RPC call.

```
public function RPC(name: string, mode: RPCMode, params args: object[]): void;
```

For RPCMode

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RPCMode.html

You don't tell it to use one of its variables, such as RPCMode.All or RPCMode. AllBuffered.

Not sure if that is your issue exactly but it certainly seems like one.

Your correct syntax should be something like this (assuming "GetID" takes one parameter)

```
networkView.RPC("GetID", RPCMode.All, playerList[b].ID);
```